# Changing amount value in PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to change the value of the product if an add-on is selected.

My code looks something like this:

```
<select name="Service">
<option value="0">Please select</option>
<option value="1">Add-on product here</option>
</select>

$srvType = $_POST["srvType"];

// now for the paypal part, I have this

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php if ($srvType==0) { echo "38.00"; } else if ($srvType==1) { echo "40.00"; } ?>"><br>
```

What I am trying to do:

Basically, when the user just buys the default product, the user gets charged $38. But, when the user selects that drop down option, the paypal should charge $40.

So I used if else and tell that if its 0, then $38. and if its 1, then its $40.

Now when I check on paypal, it only shows $38.00 and does not show $40 when option (val 1) is selected.

May I know where am I going wrong? If you require further details, I'll definitly try to provide. Thank you.

Comment: Will the post directly go to PayPal or will it make a request to your server first? Because else you'll have to change the amount using javascript and update it when the select is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `srvType` as your selectbox name. Your selectbox name is `Service`.
Replace your code `$srvType = $_POST["srvType"];` To `$srvType = $_POST["Service"];`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am so careless, I was looking at the field above. Your answer is absolutely correct.